# Keeping my local database updated .

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

I have a Cloud hosted Database, maintained by a different company. Here is my scenario:
I would like to bring down the entire database, schema and data, and keep my Local database updated real-time(sql server 2008r2).
I cannot setup replication inside SQL server, I do not have permissions on the cloud server.
I cannot use triggers. 
I cannot use linked servers
They would provide me  a copy of backup  (nightly)and access to the transacrion logs every 1 hour 
How can I use these to update my entire database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are tools to apply log changes to your db, but I'm not sure you can automate this job. [Apex](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx), [Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/experimental-tools/sql-log-rescue/)

Comment: Thanks @McNets . Can I restore the back and trans log and create a new  database in my server and then use replication to update my database ?

Comment: That's the idea, recover backup and apply log changes. Can you get a full backup?

Comment: Yes we get a full back up everynight and transaction logs every one hour . Can I use sql server log shipping to update my transaction logs every one hour ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it. I suppose you can download a trial ed. and give a try.

Comment: Thanks ! I have another issue. What if i restored the database in the same server where my destination database exists ? Do I need to create storeprocedure to update each table? Or is there any process to make it simple .  We have like 2000 tables in the database

Comment: Recover a db is similar to delete and create it again with new values.

Comment: I mean when I restore the backup and trans log from 3rd part cloud database to my local server how can I update my base tables which are also in the same server but in the different database .

Comment: I don't know how it affects to your other databases.